# Java annotation inside annotation Issue

Tags: java, annotations

hi guys is something kinda like this allowed in java:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(METHOD)
@FirstAnno
public @interface Test1 {
    Test2 t();

    @SecondAnno
    public @interface Test2 {
      // also has @FirstAnno

    }
}
```

later I use it like this;

```
class MyClass {

  @Test1.Test2 // or something like this
  public String getData(){
  }
}
```

is this possible?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such syntax of annotation declaration are allowed - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.1

Comment: does Test2 inherits annotation of its owner Test1?